# UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook

Good Morning,

I have created FB app. I am able to share my app info on FB a/c. When another person tries to login it's accessible, but when they try to share it, then this error appears:

> UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

Why does this happen?

Thank You

Comment: This issue occurs because the session is not yet updated. Therefore update the active session by implementing `onActivityResult` method

Comment: Still you didn't solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

@Piyush Gupta is right. You need to implement `onActivityResult` shown below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```